# Error installing Composer on web host via SSH

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm able to SSH into my web host(Bluehost) just fine. In my root folder(public_html) I installed composer with the following command..

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

When I run "php composer.phar" I get an error that pops up in the command line.

> [ErrorException]
> Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`

I notice in my root folder where I installed composer I keep getting a file called error.log that includes the following...

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: argv in - on line 13
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: argv in phar:///home2/websitename/public_html/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 55
>
> PHP Warning:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in phar:///home2/websitename/public_html/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 59
>
> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///home2/websitename/public_html/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 285

Not sure what to do next. My end goal is to install Laravel. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: depending on cli php version currently you may need `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /ramdisk/php/54/bin/php54-cli`